# Web MIDI API on Windows 10 - how to disconnect from MIDI device

Tags: web-midi

I am using navigator.requestMIDIAccess to query all MIDI devices connected to a Windows 10 computer. All `midiAccess.inputs` and `midiAccess.outputs` in the callback are inaccessible to other applications, such as a DAW. I would like to be able to select a MIDI input/output port to disconnect from, so it can be used by another application.

Is this possible using Web MIDI? This example does not work:

```
let output = midiAccess.outputs.get(portID);
output.close(); // closes the port
```